# D3 events in new versions

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js

I have written the following snippet:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    var svg = d3
      .select("svg")
      .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", () => {
        svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
      }))
      .append("g")
}
```

I am aware that the `d3.event` has been removed in new releases, but reading through the documentation on how to handle the events in callbacks does not make me understand how to modify this...

Can someone please explain this tiny bit to me and how to fix it to work, in a simple way that a novice like me can understand? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this migration guide](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3v6-migration-guide#event_zoom), the `d3.event.transform` must be replaced with the following

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
  let svg = d3                                // <-- I'd suggest using `let` instead of `var`
    .select("svg")
    .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", (event) => {   // <-- `event` argument
      svg.attr("transform", event.transform); // <-- use `event` here
    }))
    .append("g");
}
```